# In a Nuxt and Vue App, how can i prevent the user from accessing my admin routes directly from the address bar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have certain pages (routes) that i only want a specific type of user (admins) to navigate to. I can catch routing events when clicking on links within my app, but not when i change the url from the address bar.
How can i catch such a url change, and check the user type before allowing them to access the page?

Comment: There is something called Navigation Guards which you can set a guard for your different routes based on conditions (user roles etc.). Look it up

Comment: Is your project SPA only or something else (SSR, SSG)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Navigation Routes`.
This documentation page is a good point to start from
[Navigation Guards Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)